# Iterating through multiple elements in one for loop using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

I'm trying to scrape through multiple containers on a website to see if a certain item exists. I want to compare a specific value and if an item is found with that value it will write the price for that item and a link to where to buy it in a csv file.

I have managed to make a for loop that cycles through the value I am trying to match, however I cannot figure out how to pull the other elements I need with it. It ends up returning the values for the first container on the page and not the one that matched.

I have tried putting them inside the for loop as well as outside. I realize it isn't working because they are only finding a single element and it's not being told which container to pull it from, but I did something similar in my other script and it worked perfectly.

I also tried nesting for loops inside each other but for obvious reasons that didn't work out either. What would be the best way to handle such a situation?

```
values = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class,'text-center') and contains(text(),'Wear:')]")))
price = driver.find_element_by_class_name("item-price-display").text
buy_link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.btn-xs").get_attribute('href')
print(len(values))
for value in values:
    wear = value.text.replace("Wear: ", "")
    print(wear)
    if wear == condition:    
        print(buy_link,price)
        f.write(buy_link + "," + price)
        break
```

Full Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("permissions.default.image", 2) # Block all images to load websites faster.
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
f =  open("file.csv",'r+')
url = "http://bitskins.com"
driver.get(url)
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("market_hash_name")
key = "Dragon Lore"
condition = "0.11940288"
elem.send_keys(key,Keys.RETURN)
import time
time.sleep(3)
values = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class,'text-center') and contains(text(),'Wear:')]")))
print(len(values))
for value in values:
    price = driver.find_element_by_class_name("item-price-display").text 
    buy_link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.btn-xs").get_attribute('href')
    wear = value.text.replace("Wear: ", "")
    print(wear)
    if wear == condition:

        print(buy_link,price)
        f.write(buy_link + "," + price)
        break
```

Expected Results: (Also I'm trying to figure out how to select the 4th button and not the first button next to the add to cart.)

https://bitskins.com/view_item?app_id=730&item_id=14983017710
$1,355.23

Results I'm Getting:

https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198380422063/inventory/#730_2_15685089707 $1,350.00

Comment: What is `condition` in your code? Can you share website url?

Comment: Added full code.

Comment: Wait are you telling me it's just because I was selecting the specific div and not the full container? I had By.CLASS_NAME, "item-solo" but I changed it -_-

Comment: The element reference of <div class="text-muted text-center"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed

Comment: I tested it with Chrome. Did you add code to mine?

Comment: No I tried deleting everything and pasting that in.

Comment: I believe it's scraping to quickly. Before the search. It's printing 60 for the container length and it should be 58.

Comment: Okay. I just added a time.sleep right after the send keys and it's working. Now I need to figure out how to populate the key and condition from rows in a csv file. So it can loop through row by row. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `price` and `buy_link` is the first elements in the page and not related to the **Wear** you got with `values`. See comments in the code below.

To get 4th button you can use `.item-solo a:nth-child(4)` css selector. To use it code below inside items loop:

```
shareable_link = item.find_element_by_css_selector("a:nth-child(4)")
```

Full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re

url = "http://bitskins.com"
key = "Dragon Lore"
condition = "0.11940288"

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("permissions.default.image", 2) # Block all images to load websites faster.
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

f = open("file.csv", 'r+')

driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "market_hash_name"))).send_keys(key, Keys.RETURN)

# get all sale item container elements
items = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "item-solo")))
print(len(items))

for item in items:
    # price, buy_link and wear elements are child of sale items
    price = item.find_element_by_class_name("item-price-display").text
    buy_link = item.find_element_by_css_selector("a.btn-xs").get_attribute('href')
    shareable_link = item.find_element_by_css_selector("a:nth-child(4)").get_attribute('href')

    wear = item.find_element_by_xpath("descendant::div[contains(@class,'text-center') and contains(text(),'Wear:')]").text
    wear = re.search("\\d+.\\d+", wear)[0]
    print(wear)

    if wear == condition:
        print(buy_link, price)
        f.write(f"{buy_link},{price}")
        break
```

For [web-scraping](/questions/tagged/web-scraping), [requests](/questions/tagged/requests) and [beautifulsoap](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoap) or [another](https://www.scrapehero.com/python-web-scraping-frameworks/) scraping libraries are easier, faster and lower resource solution.

Comment: @CodeOrDie get updated code. Replaced items wait  `presence_of_all_elements_located` with `visibility_of_all_elements_located `

Comment: Use `visibility_of_all_elements_located` instead of sleep. Also you can do same thing using [tag:requests]. For data store check [tag:pandas] or create json file.

Comment: Yeah I changed it. Is there any place I can get in contact with you? I really appreciate the help. I've been workin on this stuff for about a month now and I have made some huge progress being my first time using Python. But I know the last few things are going to be a challenge and my other script could use some cleaning up because it's hanging a bit in a few spots.

Comment: @CodeOrDie you can contact me here in comments